# Best practice for touch intention

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider a simple view with three or more UITextField subviews called "A", "B", "C", and so on. The view controller implements UITextFieldDelegate and has a textFieldShouldEndEditing that looks something like the following:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(EFFUITextField *)textField
{
    return [self isValidSolution];
}
```

If the first responder is field A and the user taps field C, assuming field A passes the criteria in isValidSolution, field C will become the first responder.

Now consider the same situation but now we wish to prompt the user with an UIAlertController to allow them to override the invalid condition:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(EFFUITextField *)textField
{
    if ([self isValidSolution])
        return YES;
    [self promptUser];
    return NO;
}
```

Since UIAlertController is handled asynchronously, we will need to be able to detect that it was field C that the user tapped and make that the first responder.

What is the best practice for detecting which field the user meant to enter so that we can make it the first responder if the user chooses to override the validation discrepancy?

Comment: Use textfieldShouldBeginEditing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store whichever field you intend to resume editing in a property, then in your `UIAlertController`'s completion block call `becomeFirstResponder` on that text field. You could even skip the property if you just capture the field to resume editing in your `UIAlertController`'s completion block at the time it's created.